# How to view sharepoint task list an another site (SP 2019 on-prem)

Tags: sharepoint-designer, task-list, 2019, sharepoint-server

The requirement is to view a sharepoint task list from a subsite(not another site collection) on root site and other subsite.

Example

Task list location

root.site/subsite1/lists/tasklist/allitems.aspx

Locations for display

root.site/pages/webpartpage.aspx

root.site/subsite2/pages/webpage.aspx

I know that for a regular list, you can open a view of a list, insert data view of the list, and save as webpart to site collection. I have done this on this site collection for other lists, but when I do this for a task list, it saves fine. When I edit the webpart page I want to add the task list to, I can add the web part, and it displays on the page, but when I save the page, I get the correlation error page with a link to the web part maintenance mode.

Looking at the ULS, I see the error "Base URL does not match the first part of the URL; strUrl: '/subsite2/SitePages/Home.aspx'; strBaseUrl: '/subsite1'

Comment: Here's one way that worked "back when" and may still work in SP 2019 (but not with the modern UI). https://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2009/03/sharepoint-one-library-multiple-sites.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a list on another site, you can try to use Page viewer web part to show the list on the target page. More information, refer to [Display a web page, folder, or file on a classic SharePoint page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/display-a-web-page-folder-or-file-on-a-classic-sharepoint-page-7f61feec-9b3d-4805-a960-07636ba59527)

Or you can use Embed iframe code to display the list view page.
[Add content to your page using the Embed web part](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-content-to-your-page-using-the-embed-web-part-721f3b2f-437f-45ef-ac4e-df29dba74de8)

Comment: This brings the top navigation along with it, and can result in people navigating within the iframe or web page web part.